# how to change hudson's default view?

Tags: hudson

i'm having problem with changing default view. can you say me how to do it properly? hudson's wiki can't help right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. There is an option for it in configuration menu.

[EDIT]  Manage Hudson/Configure System
(the default is All)

Answer (score 1):

As William's answer notes, this is the proper way to change the default view. 
Here is a sample dashboard view which I've configured to be the default one.

http://soafarm.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/sample-hudson-dashboard-2/

Note that once you've set up an alternate view as the default, it's possible to delete the original default view if you so desire.